# how to set the interval at which this websockets data is fetched?

Tags: javascript, websocket

This is the code --->

```
const delay = 5000;
    
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@trade');
let priceElement1 = document.getElementById('ethprice');
let lastPrice1 = null

ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    let stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
    priceElement1.innerText = price;
    priceElement1.style.color = !lastPrice1 || lastPrice1 === price ? 'white' : price > lastPrice1 ? '#AAFF00' : 'red';
    lastPrice1 = price;
};
```

---

Im trying to make it where instead of the data streaming to the element every 1ms it does it every 5000ms.

this is my first stack overflow post sorry if its bad i just started getting into html css and js a few months ago and i am trying to tackle more difficult tasks.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, websocket data is not fetched but received immediately after it was sent by the server. This is why websockets are used over other methods (like ajax polling) in the first place.

In your case, you could simply save incoming messages to a variable and only check that variable for updates every 5 seconds.
This could look like this:

```
const delay = 5000;

let ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@trade');
let priceElement1 = document.getElementById('ethprice');
let lastPrice1 = null
let stockObject = null;

ws.onmessage = (event) => {
    stockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
};

setInterval(() => {
    if(stockObject === null) {
        return;
    }
    let price = parseFloat(stockObject.p).toFixed(2);
    priceElement1.innerText = price;
    priceElement1.style.color = !lastPrice1 || lastPrice1 === price ? 'white' : price > lastPrice1 ? '#AAFF00' : 'red';
    lastPrice1 = price;
    stockObject = null;
}, delay);
```